# How to prevent shutdown using WM_QUERYENDSESSION or WM_ENDSESSION messages in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Is there a way to prevent shutdown or restarting on Windows using `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` or `WM_ENDSESSION` messages from the Windows API? I tried to make it by returning `FALSE` to the message but it doesn't do anything. I don't know much about receiving messages and doing things with them so any help is appreciated.

```
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (uMsg == WM_QUERYENDSESSION)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not how window procedures work. Read up on `RegisterClass`, `CreateWindowEx`, `GetMessage`.

Comment: That is not possible anymore.

Comment: But there are some cases when windows says "this app is preventing the shutdown" when doing shutdown or restart

Comment: @Lennox and if you wait (i think 30 sec might be 10) then shutdown continues anyway.  The use-case for shutdown is - I am shutting down my laptop because I have a train to catch and I need to leave now!

Comment: Read Microsoft's documentation: [Shutting Down](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/shutting-down), especially the sections on "Shutdown Notifications" and "Blocking Shutdown". Also read [Shutdown Changes for Windows Vista](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/shutdown-changes-for-windows-vista)

Answer (score 2):

Too many applications handled `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` incorrectly so its semantics has changed and it might no longer prevent a shutdown in Vista and higher.

[Shutdown Changes for Windows Vista](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/shutdown-changes-for-windows-vista)

> - Applications should not block shutdown. Respond to `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` as quickly as possible and postpone cleanup activities until processing the `WM_ENDSESSION` message.
> - Applications that must block shutdown should use the new [`ShutdownBlockReasonCreate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-shutdownblockreasoncreate) function to register a string that explains the reason to the user. The user can decide whether to continue or cancel shutdown.
> - Applications cannot rely on being able to block shutdown.

Your application window also has to be visible...

> Note that the system does not allow console applications or applications without a visible window to cancel shutdown.